# Mpd file with A-Frame does not play

Tags: html, aframe, mpeg-dash

I am trying to play a 360 degree `.mpd` file with A-Frame. Here's the codepen [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpgWXP).

The video does not show up at all and the console log shows:

`components:texture:warn Video element was defined without`src`nor`srcObject`attributes. 
three.js:20093 WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no video
255index.html:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x22a5f11bf200]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
index.html:1 WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.`

Please advise what A-Frame is not liking here or am I  missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got it to work by loading the file using shaka player. Dash.js also works. So no worries. A-Frame picks it up and renders it well once the file is loaded with external libraries like shaka or dash.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most basic example:

```
<html>
  <script src="https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <video id="video" data-dashjs-player autoplay 
             src="https://dash.akamaized.net/envivio/EnvivioDash3/manifest.mpd"></video>
    </a-assets>
    <a-videosphere src="#video"></a-videosphere>
  </a-scene>
</html>
```

Relying on [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js)